# Is it suitable to use a list for save i-th result in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

The vector `tmp` store the `i`-th result in the foor-loop. After `for-loop` I need compute the `mean()` function to each column of `sim` variable. Currently, I use the list and apply tree command to the list:
`t()`, `matrix()`, and `unlist()`.

**My code is below**

```
m   <- 5; n = 3
tmp <- numeric(n); tmp
sim <- list(); sim

set.seed(1)

for(i in 1:m){ 
# ...
tmp      <- rnorm(n)
sim[[i]] <- tmp
# ...
} # i

xx <- t(matrix(unlist(sim), n, m)); 
mean(xx[,1]);     mean(xx[,2]);     mean(xx[,3])
```

**Question.** Is it suitable to use a list here and apply tree command to it after `for-loop`?

Comment: Do you need `lapply(sim,mean)`?

Answer (score 1):

We can generate `m*n` random numbers together, store them in a matrix and get mean of each column using `colMeans`.

```
colMeans(matrix(rnorm(m*n), m, n))
```

---

If there are lot of functions in the loop which cannot be escaped, we can store the `mean` of each iteration in `temp` directly.

```
m   <- 5; n = 3
tmp <- numeric(m)

for(i in 1:m){ 
  # ...
  tmp[i] <- mean(rnorm(n))
  # ...
}

tmp
```

Comment: rnorm() is for example here only. I have apply a number function in the for-loop.

Comment: @Nick Do you need `xx` at the end of the `for` loop. We can get the `mean ` in the loop itself. check updated answer.